# Physics book recommendations for transition to PhD study

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

Now in the end of my MSc in physics I've been contemplating in enrolling in a Phd in theoretical physics. Before that I think I would do best to re-study some subjects. My question is then, what books should I follow for that? I'm thinking about getting a better understanding of classical mechanics and follow Goldstein's book and then use Griffiths' and Jackson's books for electromagnetism. Are these good books for a student who wants to have a deeper understanding of physics?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/2451

Comment: So you've done physics for about five years and want to read Jackson? Do you want to get bored to death? Unless you don't care about time efficiency, why not learn some challenging mathematics which connects all of your subjects?

Comment: Bored to death? Jackson was actually used in my course of Classical electrodynamics. Maybe Jackson is not a good book as a textbook but certainly covers some deeps things, but I only know the first chapters and then 11 to 16, but tell me other books for electromagnetism, aside Griffiths.

Mathematics that connects all of the subjects?I have a good understanding of analysis and algebra. I'm lacking a deep understanding of differential geometry but I did took a course in Riemannian Geometry and another in Mathematical Relativity...

Comment: @PML: I'm not judging if it's a good book or not, but it's for second or thrid year students and so it will not be challenging. Also use the at-symbol if you want people to see your replies. If you go into theory, a solid understanding of Lie-groups will most definately be of relevance.

Comment: @NickKidman Sorry didn't know that feature. Well, the fact that not one of my classmates have never eard of self-force or Abraham-Lorentz-Dirac force makes it a little more than a second year student book. But tell me other books. I'm looking for something that really can give me a deep understanding of the subject.

Comment: @PML for a deep understanding of Electrodynamics you should read something about QED ;)

Comment: @Nikolaj-K: Would you please recommend some books in this context?

Comment: @omehoque whoa man, replying to a 6 year old comment in a buried thread. You mean books when you already finished your Masters degree and want to relearn theoretical physics for a PhD track? Which field in particular? I'd figure after a 3 year treack you already have a good reading list.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K: Yeah, six-year is a long time. Please recommend me some books about nuclear and particle theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goldstein's and Jackson's are the examples of widely used graduate level textbooks, however it should be used already in your MSc course. Griffith's in the other hand is widely used in physics undergraduate EM course.

I don't know the level of math and physics that you have, but probably it would be good to start studying Landau-Lifshitz's Course on Theoretical Physics. Keep in mind that the level of the book is advanced, hence the authors tend to omit some "obvious" intermediate steps, such that it would take "forever" to follow their derivation. The good side of the books is all the problems inside have solutions given by the authors.

You may also benefit from the consistency of the presentations due to they all written by the same authors.

Answer (score 3):

A thorough overview of theoretical physics, from a uniform point of view and with lots of explanations is given in the 10 volumes on Theoretical Physics by Landau and Lifshitz.

Though not covering the newest things they start from scratch (though assuming some background that you surely have with a MSc) and are a nearly ideal foundation on which to build the newer stuff that you'll learn as a PhD stident.

Answer (score 0):

My reading list with the goal to have books for a more advanced and different point of view on some topics and physics in general (which is maybe also interesting for you):

Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics - V. I. Arnold
[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Classical-Mechanics-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387968903](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387968903)

Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development - Leslie E Ballentine
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/9810227078/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810227078)

Representation Theory: A First Course - William Fulton, Joe Harris
[http://www.amazon.com/Representation-Theory-Graduate-Mathematics-Readings/dp/0387974954/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387974954)

The Quantum Theory of Fields 3 Volumes - Steven Weinberg
[http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Theory-Fields-Paperback-Set/dp/052167056X/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052167056X)

Comment: From the reviews, those look like the perfect books for introducing those advanced topics. Thank you